# How to use substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have this query.

```
SELECT 
    proj.refno [Reference No.], 
    proj.projname [NNNN], 
    TotalCost= '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(ship.volfinish as int) * data.price)/1000,2) as decimal(5,2)))
 FROM 
     projects proj
 INNER JOIN 
     projdata data ON proj.controlno = data.controlno 
 INNER JOIN 
     shipment ship ON data.ctrlno = ship.dctrlno 
 WHERE 
     proj.refno IN ('item1', 'item2','item3') 
 ORDER BY 
     proj.refno
```

with this output:

```
    Reference No.           NNNN                                                TotalCost
GR-NFS52  abc123             StudentsTitle123 (NNNN: xxxxxxxxxxxxx)                                $215.45
GR-PFS53  def456             StudentsTitle456 (NNNN: xxxxxxxxxxxxx)                                $259.55
GR-SSFS43   ghi789         StudentsTitle789 (NNNN: xxxxxxxxxxxxx)                           $242.35
```

How can I make the `NNNN` column used the substring function with this output. Cause I'm not into t-sql.

```
NNNN
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have pattern like `NNNN: xxxxxxxxxxx)` in your strings you can extract this number using some simple manipulation over the string value using `charindex` and `substring`:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)
select @str = 'Students (NNNN: 9781410314291)'

select substring(@str, 
               charindex('ISBN:', @str) + 6, 
               charindex(')', @str, charindex('NNNN:', @str)) - charindex('NNNN:', @str) - 6)
```

Here we first find position of `NNNN:` substring, then position of first occurence of closing bracket `)` after this substing and taking part of string between these positions - it is exactly number you need.

In your particular case you can use `outer apply` in select query in order to make it more readable by avoiding multiple copy-pasting the same `charindex('NNNN:', proj.projname)` expression:

```
select
    proj.refno [Reference No.], 
    substring(proj.projname, 
             CALC.pos_from, 
             charindex(')', proj.projname, CALC.pos_from) - CALC.pos_from - 6) as [NNNN],
    ....
FROM projects proj
  .....
   outer apply (select charindex('NNNN:', proj.projname) as pos_from) as CALC
```

Comment: it displays `9781410314291)` i try to use `-1` after the `)` but it doesn't work so I can remove the close parenthesis

Comment: @404notfound Oh, it was a typo in the answer. Actually it should be `-6` there, since it is calculation of length of number to extract and we should decrease it by length of `ISBN: ` prefix which is exactly 6. This is needed due to our start position determined at first step - is start position of ёШЫИТё prefix, not the number itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = 'Novels for Students, vol. 52 (ISBN: 9781410314291)'

SELECT 
  REPLACE(STUFF(@str, 1, PATINDEX('% '+REPLICATE('[0-9]', 13) + '%', @str), ''), ')', '')
```

Result:

```
9781410314291
```

Comment: thanks!  I think I will now be studying `stuff`, `patindex` and `replicate` (Up vote for this)

Comment: Little thing - older ISBNs can be 10 characters instead of 13. It's safer to detect the length than hardcode them in this case.

Comment: @eftpotrm to be honest, I had no clue what ISBN was. This was a way to detect a pattern, I used 13, because that matched the test data. If data has a different length, it should be easy to adjust the script